# Mysql concatenation fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
update `users` set `email` = 'web+'.`id`.'@gmail.com'
```

Can i achieve this. Basically all that i am trying to do is updating email id in a special faction i.e insert the row's primary key between PLUS(+) and AT(@) in web+@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
UPDATE `users` SET `email` = CONCAT('web+', `id`, '@gmail.com' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CONCAT` function like this:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `email` = CONCAT('web+', CAST(id as CHAR), '@gmail.com')
```

Note you need to `CAST` the `id` to `CHAR` for `CONCAT` to work